# Embed SVG into HTML

Tags: html, svg

I need to embed a SVG file into HTML file, the SVG's dimensions are bit larger. so, I need the SVG to be re-sized to the screen resolution. Is there any way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an SVG file to fit in a container the first thing to do is to set a `viewBox` attribute and remove `width` and `height` attributes from the root `<svg>` element:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 200" ... >
```

The values of a `viewBox` are: `x y width height`. Read more in the [SVG specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how complex is that SVG, but at least you can put whole description under one group , and then use transform="scale(SF)" whereas "SF" stands for scaling factor. Default is 1 (100%), so use little script:

```
 TransFrm = "scale(" + SF + ")";
 yourElement.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", TransFrm);
```

Or if you mean resizing by viewBox then `<rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"/>`.

Or if you mean something else take a look at: http://janistoolbox.typepad.com/blog/2009/12/svgauto-resize-svg-on-an-html-page.html

Good luck.